# tiff specification for 16-bit grayscale

Tags: java, c++, tiff, codec, specifications

for an xray-application I need a 16-bit grayscale tiff image.
However, reading through the tiff specification (Revision 6.0, Final — June 3, 1992), I just found, that 4 and 8 bit are specified for grayscale images (c.f. Section 4).

Is there a newer specification and where can I get it? Or can someone please explain me the 16-bit grayscale specification, such that I can code it (in C/C++ and Java)? 
Is it just setting `BitsPerSample = 16` or must I do something else?

Thanks

Comment: for what i know TIFF is just a container for the real images, also why not using a library http://www.libtiff.org/ ?

Comment: what is your input? you just need to use a short int (or any data type which is 2 bytes) for every pixel.

Comment: But how can I get sure, that the 2 bytes (for one pixel) are not interpreted as two pixels (one byte per pixel)?

Comment: TIFF has a [BitsPerSample tag](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/bitspersample.html) to specify (big surprise) the number of bits per sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

libtiff supports 16 bpp images. Such images, produced by libtiff, are recognized by another programs, such as ImageJ - you can use it for testing.
libtiff library is available here http://www.libtiff.org/ and can be used in C/C++ programs.

Answer (score 0):

Note that LibTIFF is:

1. NOT at *libtiff.org*.  It's at **https://gitlab.com/libtiff/libtiff** .  Someone stole their website back over 20 years ago (imagine that), and *libtiff.org* contains but an old version!
2. Has buffer overflow issues, so be careful when reading TIFF files of unknown provenance with it!
3. Has been reported to be slow when writing multi-frame images.  Apparently time to write a frame grows proportionally with the frame number.  Google *TinyTIFF* for one existing solution, or spin your own.